# App with json and sqlite crashes if internet connection is not available

Tags: android, json, sqlite, listview

I am working on JSON data fetching and displaying but before that I store it in Sqlite.

After fetching from that Sqlite table, it works fine when internet is available but app automatically closed when internet connection is not available. I am using hash-map custom adapter to showing data in listview. I have created a fetchdata method from SqlHelper class

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
 {
// Create an array
arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    int state = NetworkUtilClass.checkInternetConenction(getActivity());
    if (state == 1) {
        // jsonobject = new JSONObject(str1);
        jsonobject = JSONFunction.getJSONfromURL("url");
        JSONObject collection = null;
        try {
            collection = jsonobject.getJSONObject("collection");
        }
            catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONArray response = null;
        try {
            response = collection.getJSONArray("response");
        }
            catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject jsonobject1 = null;
            try {
                jsonobject1 = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                noticeId = jsonobject1.getString("id").toString();
                noticeTitle = jsonobject1.getString("title").toString();
                noticeDescription = jsonobject1.getString("description").toString();
                noticePublishedBy = jsonobject1.getString("publishedBy").toString();
                noticeValidFrom = jsonobject1.getString("validFrom").toString();
                noticeValidTo = jsonobject1.getString("validTo").toString();
                Log.e(noticeId, "show");
                Log.e(noticeTitle, "show");
                Log.e(noticeDescription, "show");
                //demo_database.insertData(noticeTitle,noticeDescription,noticePublishedBy,noticeValidFrom,noticeValidTo);
                            demo_database.insertNoticeData(noticeId,noticeTitle,noticeDescription, noticePublishedBy,
                            noticeValidFrom, noticeValidTo);
               } 
                   catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        onPostExecute(null);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Void args) 
  {
    // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
    getData();
    demo_database.close();

// Close the progressdialog
mProgressDialog.dismiss();
  }
  }

  private void getData() {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       try {
        arraylist = demo_database.fetchNoticeData();
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       listview = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
       listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ListView clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    });

    // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
    adapter = new NoticeListViewAdapter(getActivity(), arraylist);

    // Set the adapter to the ListView
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
  }
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: remove onpostresult(null),

Answer (score 0):

Actually the thing is that when you are trying to access the json through url when internet is not available so the json Array with name response get no items in that so it got Null and when you try to execute For loop in which you give the length of json array it would be crash because of null pointer exception..

Your App is Crashing on the for Loop Right?

Comment: Could you please split this three lines into separate sentences. I am not a native but I have barely any clue what you are talking about.

Comment: Simply its Json Array With Name Response contain Null When the Internet is not available

Comment: Ok, so edit your answer please so that it is understandable. (by the way: English is a language where you only write names with a capital letter...) Camel Case Reading Is Kind Of Confusing And Irritating...

Comment: Simply its json array with name response contain null when the internet is not available

Comment: Ok seem like you didn't understand me: Please update your **answer**. I mean the 3 lines of combined words without any sense above your avatar image. I don't mean the comments and I don't wanted you to repeat yourself in the comment. So again: *Please update and improve your text INSIDE the answer!* Thank you.

Comment: My app not crashing but it . when internet connection available then Asynktask is executed and then data stor in database and fetch in listview , but when internet not available the getdata() method doesn,t show anything and without error app closed in mobil.Its works in emulater